Is it possible to pass a python list slice as reference?
I was playing with python to try to reduce memory usage using various methods. One question that arose is if there's a way to pass a list slice as reference to the original list.
The reason was the following simple code:
def reverse_list_inplace(self, s: list[str]) -> None:
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return

    s[0], s[-1] = s[-1], s[0]
    self.reverse_list_inplace(s[1:-1])

As you can guess, the intended output for, let's say,
string = ['1','2','3','4','5']
would be
string = ['5','4','3','2','1'].
However, the output gets to be
string = ['5','2','3','4','1'].
That happens because the the slice s[1:-1] is copied to the new recursive call, which switches the '2' and the '4' of the copy, not of the original.
Would there be any way in python (without passing indexes as parameters) to pass s[1:-1] as a reference to a portion of the list instead of passing the copy of it?
EDIT: Maybe I was not very clear. I'm not asking for a solution for the problem. This example I invented to ask the question about passing a slice by reference.
EDIT: The naming of the function was misleading so I fixed it to reflect that I care about list slices, not strings.

String slices always copy. But strings already have reverse iterators reversed(s), so what's the point? Maybe you should explain your use-case.

Reversing a list in-place would simply be s[:] = s[::-1].  There's no need for recursion, or even a loop.

It is possible to pass the list and slice object separately, like: self.reverseString(s, slice(1,-1)). Is that not enough?

Note that while Python's native sequences always copy on slice, slicing numpy arrays does not copy data, but instead creates a view; thus, if you use np.array(['5','2','3','4','1']) instead (and you replace len(s) with s.shape[0]), your code will work as you expected it to.

why can't you just pass s? it would pass the whole list in order. Its less code and s[1:-1] is the same as s.
EDIT1:
index -1 is the last element of a list, can you provide ur whole reversal code? I can test it but -1 is just the last index
EDIT2: Just remembered reversed() exists
testList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

print(testList)
print(list(reversed(testList)))

Outputs:
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]


No, it is not the same.  It will have one less element.

That is the whole reversal code. s[1:-1] = ['2','3','4'] in the example above. But won't work because it reverses a copy.
